# why css transform rotate make text ugly

Tags: css, transform, antialiasing

some browser (for me: firefox & chrome on XP) don't seem to apply anti-aliasing on text with CSS rotation

exemple: http://dabblet.com/gist/4281185

Why they apply on images but not text ?

Comment: Low quality implementation of a very new feature.  We should probably be glad there is any support at all.

Comment: Not so new, it exist since firefox 3.5 (June 2009) and 1st chrome version (December 2008) http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: It is worth noting that while the implementation is fairly old, that only certain modules (maybe 4/50) of CSS3 have just recently been formally ratified (think 2011/2012).  As far as the entire world is concerned, text rotation is a new feature.

Comment: sometime in chrome `translateZ(0)`  helps

Comment: There are a few bugs in webkit that prevent anti aliasing in different situations. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82268&q=anti%20aliasing%20rotate&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary - this is one of them.

Comment: `translateZ(0)` seam to work good (on Chrome+win7) I add it to my test: http://dabblet.com/gist/4281185 I will test it later on XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad text quality is obviously "fault" of web browser you use, but you should just wait some time and it should be fixed. As web developers learn how to use new features, browser programmers must implement them, and that takes some time to work correctly. Check it in next version of the browser - if text rotation will be growing more and more popular browsers will handle it better, to display more web pages correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use 3D transforms. Using 3D transform properties, even if you're not actually doing any 3D transforms can enhance performance as follow:

1. It'll kick on the ol' GPU and get smoother performance.
2. It will crap-up (thin out) the text in the default state of the button, so it's not a suprise when the transition starts.

WebKit has that nasty (I'd call it a bug) where text being transformed/transitioned looks all thin and crappy. The text will look good by default but you'll get flashing and thinning when the button is in transition or gets transformed.

hope this helps.